# SVN, get the change set of a branch, based on branching point

Tags: svn

I've created a SVN branch that contains bugfixes that I've to port the trunk. Therefore, I need the complete change set of the branch in a diff file and apply it to the trunk.

I used `svn log --stop-on-copy` to get the revision where the branch was created. Let's say the revision is `r58483`.

Now I create the diff between the branch point and the head of my branch:

```
svn diff -r r58483:HEAD https://my.repos/componentA/branches/branch1
```

My question: Am I using the correct solution?

Comment: That should get you the diff you are searching for. But: Would be a reintegration merge not be more likely what you want to achieve? See: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.reintegrate

Comment: @yeti, the branch shall be kept alive. As far as I can remember a "reintegration merge" will cause the branch to be cut. Or am I wrong?

Comment: If I am reading the documentation right the branch does not get deleted: "Now that your private branch is merged to trunk, you may wish to remove it from the repository: $ svn delete [...]